# Custom database with EF

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I have been scouting around trying to figure out how I could implement a `DBProvider` to generate a `DBContext` for a completely custom database with no avail. Now, this database uses standard SQL for communications, but the backend is incompatible with the given providers eg. SQL Server, Oracle etc.

I want to be able to leverage the Entity Framework to model and execute commands on this database and I also want to use LINQ based queries directly from the generated DBContext.

This database is split and organized into a few submodules which takes care of different areas of the schema & design.

How would I go about integrating the current objects into a usable provider?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You made a custom database? Does this help http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping

Comment: Yes, you can think of it as a collection of XML files compatible with SQL queries. As for the link, interesting read, but I am looking for a database first method.

Comment: Why don't you load those xml files into a classic database. An XML database doesn't seem very efficient or practical to me. Idk maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: The database does not actually use the XML format. It was said just for clarity and understanding. It's purpose is to optimize mobile distributions, such as a database on a USB.